# PHP can't echo to next page

Tags: php, save, echo

This page worked fine and it saved to db as it should be suddenly it stopped echo to the next page.
As you can see I have a  and in my php I have if($query){

//if successful query

echo '';

This has worked but now suddenly it stopped working for some reasons.

Any help please!

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>Inctive</title>
                <meta name="description" content="Welcome to our demo application.">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nav.css">
            </head>
            <?php

            //include database configuration

            $dbhost = "127.0.0.1";

            $dbuser = "root";

            $dbpass = "root";

            $dbname = "inctive";

            $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$dbname) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');


            if(isset($_POST['save'])){


            extract($_REQUEST);

            //sql insert statement

            $query=mysqli_query($conn,"insert into identifyRisk SET 
            referenceNumber='$referenceNumber', 
            riskName='$riskName',
            riskDescription='$riskDescription',
            division='$division',
            businessUnit='$businessUnit',
            location='$location',
            businessObjective='$businessObjective', 
            perspective='$perspective', 
            identifiedBy='$identifiedBy'
            ") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

            //insert query to the database

            if($query){

            //if successful query

            echo '<a href="analyseRisk.php">';

            }

            }

            ?>
            <body>
                <div id="wrapper">
                    <header style="margin-left: 3px;">
                        <nav id="coreMenu">
                            <ul>
                                <li><img src="images/AssureantLogo.jpg" class="logoMenu"></li>
                                <li><a href="administrationAndSecurity">Administration & Security</a></li>
                                <li><a href="governance">Governance</a></li>
                                <li><a href="selectRisk.php">Risk</a></li>
                                <li><a href="compliance">Compliance</a></li>
                                <li style="float:right; background-color: #66b0d1; margin-right: 5px;"><a href="signIn">Log Out - User: dein</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                        <label class="headlinePage">Identify Risk</label>   
                    </header>
                        <section class="tableBackground">
                            <form action="#" method="post">
                                <table class="insertField">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="inputFieldHeadline">
                                                <label for="referenceNumber">Reference Number:</label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="inputFieldField">
                                                <input type="text" id="referenceNumber" name="referenceNumber" placeholder="Will be auto generated">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="inputFieldHeadline">
                                                <label for="riskName">Risk Name:</label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="inputFieldField">
                                                <input type="text" id="riskName" name="riskName" placeholder="Enter Risk Name" >
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="inputFieldHeadline">
                                                <label for="riskDescription">Risk Description:</label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="inputFieldField">
                                                <input type="text" id="riskDescription" name="riskDescription" placeholder="Enter Risk Description">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="inputFieldHeadline">
                                                <label for="division">Division:</label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="inputFieldField">
                                                <input type="text" id="division" list="divisionList" name="division" placeholder="Please Select">
                                                <datalist id="divisionList">
                                                    <option value="First" />
                                                    <option value="Second" />
                                                    <option value="Third" />
                                                    <option value="Fourth" />
                                                    <option value="Fifth" />
                                                </datalist>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="inputFieldHeadline">
                                                <label for="businessUnit">Business Unit:</label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="inputFieldField">
                                                <input type="text" id="businessUnit" list="businessUnitList" name="businessUnit" placeholder="Please Select">
                                                <datalist id="businessUnitList">
                                                    <option value="First of 1" />
                                                    <option value="Second of 1" />
                                                    <option value="Third of 1" />
                                                    <option value="Fourth of 1" />
                                                    <option value="Fifth of 1" />
                                                </datalist>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="inputFieldHeadline">
                                                <label for="location">Location:</label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="inputFieldField">
                                                <input type="text" id="location" list="locationList" name="location" placeholder="Please Select">
                                                <datalist id="locationList">
                                                    <option value="Brisbane" />
                                                    <option value="Gold Coast" />
                                                    <option value="Sydney" />
                                                    <option value="Darwin" />
                                                    <option value="Perth" />
                                                </datalist>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="inputFieldHeadline">
                                                <label for="businessObjective">Business Objective:</label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="inputFieldField">
                                                <input type="text" id="businessObjective" list="businessObjectiveList" name="businessObjective" placeholder="Please Select">
                                                <datalist id="businessObjectiveList">
                                                    <option value="First Objective" />
                                                    <option value="Second Objective" />
                                                    <option value="Third Objective" />
                                                    <option value="Fourth Objective" />
                                                    <option value="Fifth Objective" />
                                                </datalist>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="inputFieldHeadline">
                                                <label for="perspective">Perspective:</label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="inputFieldField">
                                                <input type="text" id="perspective" name="perspective" placeholder="Enter Perspective" >
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="inputFieldHeadline">
                                                <label for="identifiedBy">Identified by:</label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="inputFieldField">
                                                <input type="text" id="identifiedBy" name="identifiedBy" placeholder="Verify your name!">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>                           
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <div class="nextPrevButton">
                                    <!--
                                    <input type="button" name="b1" value="next" onclick="location.href='next_pare.html'">
                                    -->
                                    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Next">
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </section>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Might not be used but is good to have it here -->
                    <!--
                    <footer>
                        <p>Some copyright or nothing</p>
                    </footer>
                    -->
                </div>


            </body>


            </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to close maker **a**

```
if($query){

  //if successful query

  echo '<a href="analyseRisk.php">analyseRisk</a>';

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want to achieve but there is some thing wrong with the echo code:

```
echo '<a href="analyseRisk.php">';
```

if you wanne a link then you should do it like this

```
echo '<a href="analyseRisk.php">click here please</a>';
```

if you wanne to auto redirect to analyseRisk.php then

```
header("Location: analyseRisk.php");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just close the anchor tag

```
<a hre='/whateverUrl' >Click Here</a>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thanks @RJK will keep in mind and I was trying to give simple answer that was the issue with the problematic code here.

Answer (score 1):

Close the anchor tag in your echo

`echo '<a href="analyseRisk.php">Something..</a>';`